# Case Insensitive group by in Presto

Tags: presto

By default, the Presto performs case sensitive group by. But I wanted to know how to do case insensitive group by. One method is convert all the things in the column to lower case and then perform group by ie

```
select * from ( select lower(name_of_the_column)), other_columns from table)
where conditions..
group by name_of_the_column
```

One way we can reduce time is by putting the conditions in the select statment inside the brackets. Is there any better method?

Comment: Did you measure that wrapping with subquery reduces time? AFAIK `select lower(name_of_the_column), ... group by lower(name_of_the_column)` should work the same.

Comment: yaa that works. Thanks.

Comment: I'll turn my comment into an answer then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to push `lower(...)` into a subquery. If you simply write:

```
SELECT lower(name_of_the_column), ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY lower(name_of_the_column) -- or just "GROUP BY 1"
```

Presto will do the conversion to lowercase only once for each row (not twice).